# Does not work routing on prod environment

Tags: php, symfony

Does not work routing on prod environment, but on dev all pages load.

Apache log:

> [Fri May 17 23:50:05 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not
>   exist: /mnt/d/web/project/web/front

Browser:

> Not Found The requested URL /front was not found on this server.

Comment: mod_rewrite in Apache loaded?

Answer (score 1):

I changed in virtualHost:

from "AllowOverride none to "AllowOverride All". Now, it work.